# I cannot stop a function from executate

Tags: javascript

Every time I open the modal, a function is executed:

```
// Open modal
function modal_openModal(id, method, data, key) {
    let div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = "flex";

    modal_closeModal(div, id);
    if(id == "modalCategory"){
        modalAddCategory("execute", method, data, key)
    }else if(id == "modalProduct"){

    }
}

//Modal add category
function modalAddCategory(execute, method, updateData, key){
    let form = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form");
    let submitbtn = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form button");
    let categoryInput = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form input[name='categoryTitle']");
    
    // Putting value in the input if it is for update
    if(method == "update"){
        categoryInput.value = updateData.category
    }
    console.log(method)
    console.log("--------")

    // Event listener - submit btnm
    realtimedb_eventSubmitBtn(submitbtn, categoryData, form);


    // Data
    function categoryData() {
        let data = {
            category: categoryInput.value
        };

        // Register data
        if(method == "update"){
            realtimedb_update("Categories", data, key)
        }else if(method == "create") {
            realtimedb_create("Categories", data);
        }
    }
}


// Event listener - submit btn 
function realtimedb_eventSubmitBtn(btn, nameFunction, form) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (element) => {
        element.preventDefault();

        nameFunction();
    
        form.reset();
    })
}
```

The function of the modal is basically to change the display and execute the function.

The problem is that when I close the modal and open it again, the "modallAddCategory" function continues to be executed, that is, the process will be done twice.

I already put return, tried some checks, but nothing worked. How do I resolve this?

Comment: How is `modalAddCategory()` being called?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: If modalAddCategory is being called multiple times, you're adding multiple EventListeners to the submit button (I think that's what you're referencing about what's being run twice).

Comment: No. When I open the modal, the function is executed. When I close the modal, the function has not stopped. Then I open the modal again and the function is executed, but now twice because the previous one was not stopped

Comment: Hello. looks like you need to stop the user to mess with the UI when the first function is still in progress. How about a throbber/loader?

Comment: interesting this throbber, but does it have another way?

Comment: yeah, disable buttons that could close the modal before the function ends its operations. I don't recommend this though.

Comment: It can also be done by storing a boolean variable which decides whether the function still in progress or not. But I see this as a playful and unreasonable change. Playful because it will cover the case where first we are letting the user close the modal and open it quickly. Least recommended.